# 1 Volume controller for multiple players?

Tags: html, audio, range, controls, volume

Is there an easy way to repeat this code to create a volume controller that works for 4 different players simultaneously? I've managed to get it to work for one player at any given point by changing the myAudio(x) value but any more than that seems to confuse it.

// Global variables and controls

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
    
var volumeControl = document.getElementById("vol-control");
    
    var setVolume = function(){
        vid.volume = this.value / 100;
    };



var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio(1)"); 

var volumeControl2 = document.getElementById("vol-control2");
    
    var setVolume2 = function(){
        audio.volume = this.value / 100;
    };
```

//event listeners

```
volumeControl.addEventListener('change',setVolume);
volumeControl.addEventListener('input',setVolume);

volumeControl2.addEventListener('change',setVolume2);
volumeControl2.addEventListener('input',setVolume2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate

HTML

```html
<div id="audvid">
  <video.../>
  <audeo.../>
</div>
```

event listeners

```js
document.getElementById("audvid").addEventListener("change", setVolume)
document.getElementById("audvid").addEventListener("input", setVolume)
```

change whatever is accessed

```
const setVolume = function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (["AUDIO", "VIDEO"].includes(tgt.tagName)) {
    tgt.volume = tgt.value / 100;
  }
};
```

change any audio/video

```
const setVolume = function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  [...document.querySelectorAll("AUDIO", "VIDEO")].forEach(ele => {
    ele.volume = tgt.value / 100;
  })
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I shouldn't have included the video element. I have a separate range control that works fine for that. I want to implement 2 sliders in total. One that effects the video output, and another one that effects the combined output of 4 audio players. I can get it to work for one of the myAudio players, but not all of them simultaneously. I hope this clears up my question slightly?

Comment: the answer does not change much. You should have all tools necessary in my answer